# RxAndroid how to(is it possible) put some parameters into Observable

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

My trouble is that I need to put some parameters(String as example) into Observable for some work with it, how can i do it, and is it possible? Pretty simple sample is that how we send params into AsyncTask:

```
Boolean[] myTaskParams = { true, true, true };
myAsyncTask = new myAsyncTask ().execute(myTaskParams);
```

Comment: Also, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28407277/create-an-observable-that-would-accept-arguments/28410615#28410615

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send your params to normal function and return your Obsverable type and let it run in background.

```
public T yourFunction(A a,B b,C c){
    ...
    return t;
}

Observable.from(yourFunction(a,b,c))
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
      .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
      .subscribe(yourTObserver);
```

Comment: This won't run `yourFunction` in the background thread but execute it before the Observable is even created in the current thread.

Comment: What is the difference from `fromCallable`?

Comment: when using a `Callable` it's not calling the `.call()` method yet that produces a `T`. In your case, you call the `yourFunction` method and observe the resulting `T`. You have to capture the `yourFunction` in an object that gets turned into an observable. In Lambda style something like `Observable.from(() -> yourFunction(a,b,c))`

Comment: Ya thank you I got the point. `fromCallable` is new to me though

Answer (score 1):

When you write your async task, either capture the parameters:

```
Object[] params = { false, true, true};
Observable
.fromCallable(() -> { use params; return value; })
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(...);
```

or transform the parameters:

```
Observable.just(params)
.map(p -> { use p; return value; });
...
```

or produce many values for a single set of parameters:

```
Observable.just(params)
.flatMap(p -> { use p, return Observable.something; })
...
```